# Searching a single column for multiple values at once in R

Tags: r

I am working with a trade dataset, and I need to subset out all rows which represent goods going to China, Korea, Dominican Republic, and several others. I can programmatically create this list, and I know how to subset the trade dataset for anyone of these countries, but not all of them at once. What I have tried is using the which() function.

```
DesiredSubset = TotalTradeData[which(TotalTradeData$Destination.Code == c(List of desired country codes), ]
```

This runs but produces this:

```
Warning message: In DesiredSubset = TotalTradeData[which(TotalTradeData$Destination.Code ==  : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

It subsets out some rows, but nowhere close to all of the ones that I need.
I'm pretty sure that this would work if I just typed all the codes with | in between as an or operator, but I have to do this for dozens of codes dozens of times so that isn't practical.

How can I subset out all of the rows containing any one of the country codes in my list?

Comment: Try `TotalTradeData[which(TotalTradeData$Destination.Code %in% c(List of desired country codes), ]`

Comment: BTW, I am from Dominican Republic :)

Answer (score 2):

In your case you are using the wrong logical operator, use `%in%` instead of `==`.

```r
# The data
TotalTradeData <- data.frame(
  Destination.Code = c('COL', 'DOM', 'KOR', 'CHINA', 'USA', 'BRA'),
  variable1 = letters[1:6]
)

TotalTradeData
#>   Destination.Code variable1
#> 1              COL         a
#> 2              DOM         b
#> 3              KOR         c
#> 4            CHINA         d
#> 5              USA         e
#> 6              BRA         f

TotalTradeData[TotalTradeData$Destination.Code %in% c('DOM', 'KOR', 'CHINA'), ]
#>   Destination.Code variable1
#> 2              DOM         b
#> 3              KOR         c
#> 4            CHINA         d
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>